# Spring-framework Neo4jRepository function, findById, causes a Cypher Error

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm, spring-data-neo4j-5

**Background**

My spring data neo4j application is giving out cypher errors.

This is odd because I am using neo ogm to manage all of my cyper statements, I have not written any cypher myself.

Here are my errors:

**Cypher Error in CLI output**

```
Error executing Cypher "Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError"; Code: Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError; Description: Invalid input '|': expected whitespace, comment, a relationship pattern, '.', node labels, '[', "=~", IN, STARTS, ENDS, CONTAINS, IS, '^', '*', '/', '%', '+', '-', '=', "<>", "!=", '<', '>', "<=", ">=", AND, XOR, OR, ',' or ']...
```

**OGM error in CLI output after the cypher error**

```
...nested exception is org.neo4j.ogm.exception.CypherException: Error executing Cypher \"Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError\"; Code: Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError; Description: Invalid input '|': expected whitespace, comment, a relationship pattern, '...
```

**Error locating the spot in my code where the error originates (GenericService)**

```
...myproject.service.GenericService.find(GenericService.java:39) ~[classes/:na]...
```

**Line 39 of GenericService**

`Optional<T> object = getRepository().findById(id, depth);`

**Where I'm stuck**

`findById` is declared in the springframework.data.neo4j.repository.Neo4jRepository.java as `Optional<T> findById(ID id, int depth);`

I have recently started using neo4jrepository instead of graphrepository since I switched to the Spring data neo4j 5.0.0.

So, I think I have located the issue in the code, but its not my code, its the library, but I cant' believe that a the most recent neo4j ogm was released with a bug in the `findById` function.

**Question**

How do I get past this Cypher Error? Where could this problem be originating from?

**UPDATE 1**

I am using neo4j-ogm-version 3.0.0, spring-boot 2.0.0.M3, Neo4J is 3.2.3 and spring-data-neo4j 5.0.0.RELEASE,

**UPDATE 2**

Could it be that my id is instantiated as a `Long` whereas Neo4jRepository.java has is instantiated as an `ID`?

**MORE CONTEXT** in GenericService.java

```
public T find(Long id) {
    Optional<T> object = getRepository().findById(id, DEPTH_ENTITY);
    if(object.isPresent())
            return object.get();
    return null;
}
```

**UPDATE 3**

springframework.data.neo4j.repository.Neo4jRepository.java contains

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface Neo4jRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends PagingAndSortingRepository<T, ID> {

    <S extends T> S save(S s, int depth);

    <S extends T> Iterable<S> save(Iterable<S> entities, int depth);

    Optional<T> findById(ID id, int depth);

    Iterable<T> findAll();

    Iterable<T> findAll(int depth);

    Iterable<T> findAll(Sort sort);

    Iterable<T> findAll(Sort sort, int depth);

    Iterable<T> findAllById(Iterable<ID> ids);

    Iterable<T> findAllById(Iterable<ID> ids, int depth);

    Iterable<T> findAllById(Iterable<ID> ids, Sort sort);

    Iterable<T> findAllById(Iterable<ID> ids, Sort sort, int depth);

    /**
     * Returns a {@link Page} of entities meeting the paging restriction provided in the {@code Pageable} object.
     * {@link Page#getTotalPages()} returns an estimation of the total number of pages and should not be relied upon for accuracy.
     *
     * @param pageable
     * @return a page of entities
     */
    Page<T> findAll(Pageable pageable);

    /**
     * Returns a {@link Page} of entities meeting the paging restriction provided in the {@code Pageable} object.
     * {@link Page#getTotalPages()} returns an estimation of the total number of pages and should not be relied upon for accuracy.
     *
     * @param pageable
     * @param depth
     * @return a page of entities
     */
    Page<T> findAll(Pageable pageable, int depth);
}
```

Comment: What's your Neo4j version ?

Comment: Neo4j is version 3.2.3 @nmervaillie

Comment: Can you post the code of your repository and your entity ?

Comment: @nmervaillie springframework.data.neo4j.repository.Neo4jRepository.java is my repository and DEPTH_ENTITY is just `public static final int DEPTH_ENTITY = 1;` I have added the repo file code in UPDATE 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are not very familiar with Java and its generics type.

Let's take it step by step :

1. You need to define an entity, for example

   ```
   @NodeEntity
   public class User {
       @Id @GeneratedValue
       private Long id;
       ...
   ```
2. Then define a repository extending Neo4jRepository from SDN

   ```
   public interface UserRepository extends Neo4jRepository<User, Long> {
   }
   ```

This way you specialize `Neo4jRepository` by indicating you want a repository to manage `User` whose identity is defined by a `Long`.
The method defined in `Neo4jRepository` :

```
Optional<T> findById(ID id, int depth);
```

Becomes this specialized version in your repository

```
Optional<User> findById(Long id, int depth);
```

You never use `Neo4jRepository` directly, only the sub-interfaces you define.

For much more details please check the [Spring Data commons reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.definition). Also consider having a look at java generic types.

**Update**

Besides the fact the use of SDN is incorrect, I think the cause of the error is that you use a Neo4j version < 3.1

I highly doubt you are using 3.2.3 as specified in your comment. Please double check.

Comment: upon seeing your update, I rechecked my neo4j and saw that I have a neo4j 3.0.11 running on localhost and 3.2.3. running on http://127.0.0.1/ concurrently ( i didn't even know this was possible). This is probably the heart of my problem. I will accept your answer if I get the code running after deleting the old neo4j.